# How do I cancel a dotnet core worker process from code from ExecuteAsync?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

So I have a dotnet core worker process, I want to shutdown the worker process on some condition.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
     {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("This is a worker process");
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                 if (condition == true)
                  //do something to basically shutdown the worker process with failure code.
                
                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);                
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried to break out of the loop but that does not really shutdown the worker process.

```
//----this does not work-----
//even after doing this, Ctrl-C has to be done to shutdown the worker.
if (condition == true) break;
```

Comment: Throw an exception detailing the failure? If you really want to die hard you can use `Environment.FailFast`, but that skips all cleanup, so it's better to shift the burden of exiting to the highest level (catch exception, log, then `Environment.Exit`).

Comment: Throw an exception or do you have access to the `CancellationTokenSource`? If so an alternate is to call [`Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 15):

Exiting an `IHostedService` doesn't terminate the application itself. An application may run multiple `IHostedService`, so it wouldn't make sense for one of them to bring down the entire application.

To terminate the application, the hosted service class must accept an [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instance, and call [StopApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) when it wants to terminate the application. The interface will be injected by the DI middleware :

```cs
class MyService:BackgroundService
{
    IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;

    public MyService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        _lifetime=lifetime;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ...
            if (condition == true)
            {
                   _lifeTime.StopApplication();
                   return;
            }
                 
            ...            
        }
    }

}
```

This will signal all other background services to terminate gracefully and cause `Run()` or `RunAsync()` to return, thus exiting the application.

*Throwing won't end the application either*.

The service has to ensure `StopApplication` is called if it wants the process to terminate, eg :

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try 
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //log the exception then
        _lifetime.StopApplication();
    }

}
```

Comment: @134204 How best can we handle situations where lets say we have to open a db connection and it fails? What would be the best location to open a db connection - what would you recommend? Is it in `StartAsync`?

Comment: In a `using` block in the location it's going to be used. There's no reason to keep a connection open for a long time, connection pooling ensures that closing and reopening a connection costs nothing. That's why all tutorials show creating connections in a `using` block.

Comment: Locks remain active as long as a transaction or a connection exist, so long-lived connections accumulate locks and can block other connections or lead to deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use:

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Within your if clause.

This is particularly important if you are writing Windows Services using a BackgroundWorker class so that the Windows Service Management system will use configured recovery options correctly.

Example see [Create a Windows Service using BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service)