# Is there a way to perform some checks before successfully start service, using BackgroundService C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build windows service using BackgroundService base class. And I'd like to make some checks, before service starts, and if those checks fail - abort starting of service at all.

What I have now - I do checks inside MainTask, and throw exception when my check fails.
But in this case when I start service - it doesn't stop immediately!
In Event Viewer I see several records:

> 1. Service started successfully.
> 2. Category: MyWindowsService.MyWorker
>    EventId: 0
>
> Startup checks are not ok!
> Exception:
> System.Exception:....

Also, for some time I see "Running" in status of my service, and this "Running" label is kept until I refresh Services.

What I want to achieve - service is not started at all, when my check fails, I see some error message from Services, like "Service cannot be started".

My worker code:

```
    public class MyWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyWorker> _logger;

        public CindyWorker(ILogger<MyWorker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    new MainTask().Start(stoppingToken);
                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // When the stopping token is canceled, for example, a call made from services.msc,
                // we shouldn't exit with a non-zero exit code. In other words, this is expected...
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // When the stopping token is canceled, for example, a call made from services.msc,
                // we shouldn't exit with a non-zero exit code. In other words, this is expected...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);
                Environment.ExitCode = 1;

                // Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system.
                // This is required to avoid the 'BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior', which
                // performs one of two scenarios:
                // 1. When set to "Ignore": will do nothing at all, errors cause zombie services.
                // 2. When set to "StopHost": will cleanly stop the host, and log errors.
                //
                // In order for the Windows Service Management system to leverage configured
                // recovery options, we need to terminate the process with a non-zero exit code.

                Environment.Exit(1);

            }
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I tried to not catch exceptions, but this doesn't give desired result.

Comment: The `BackgroundService` type is not directly related to Windows SCM (service-control-manager), and none of the code you've posted show you interfacing with types from `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` - so it could be anything. Please post more context.

Comment: Surely they are using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService. @mykola is MainTask.Start async? If so you need to await it to catch its exception in your catch blocks.

Comment: @JakubFojtik Whether or not they use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService` is orthogonal to whether or not a program or project actually interfaces with Windows Service Control - the OP says they want to build a Windows Service, but `BackgroundService` won't help without _first_ getting up the SCM interface (i.e. you can write a Windows Service in C# (that appears in `services.msc`) _without_ using `BackgroundService` nor `IHostedService`) - and you can use `IHostedService`/`BackgroundService` within a non-Windows Service context provided you have an `IHost`, like ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `new MainTask().Start(stoppingToken);` is **async** (as opposed to *non-async* simply returning a `Task`):

If you don't await the async method its Exception may not be caught in your catch blocks. See [Where does an async Task throw Exception if it is not awaited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691114/where-does-an-async-task-throw-exception-if-it-is-not-awaited)

**EDIT:** You should stop the service cooperatively as per [How do I cancel a dotnet core worker process from code from ExecuteAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211112/how-do-i-cancel-a-dotnet-core-worker-process-from-code-from-executeasync)

Comment: Exceptions, thrown from inside MainTask() are catched, but my problem is that those exceptions are treated as part of service itself, not part of service startup process. And I need to interrupt startup somehow.